# Source of quote about UNIX as a virtual machine and C as a scripting language

Tags: c, unix

I recall a quote that goes something like this:

> Unix is the universal virtual machine and C is its scripting language.

I am looking for the origin of this quote and the exact language. I vaguely remember Eric Raymond as the proximate source, but I can't find it in his writing.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my spelling. `$embarassed`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nearest quote I could find was '***it's perhaps best to think of C as a high-level assembler for the Unix virtual machine***', found [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch14s04.html)

**Edit:** Perhaps you are referring to Eric S Raymond's book '[The Art Of Unix Programming](http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/graphics/taoup.pdf)'

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.